# response.sendRedirect is not working

Tags: java, jsp, response

I have two jsps. One is `login_first.jsp`, another one is `main.jsp`. After submit in `login_first.jsp`, I call `main.jsp`. It works fine.

I have logout button in `main.jsp` which sends control back to `login_first.jsp`. it executes `login_first.jsp` but page is not loading.
Please help.

login_first.jsp

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%
try {   
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); 
    if ("Submit".equals(request.getParameter("SubmitButton"))) {                                
        session.setAttribute("userLoggedIn", "true");               
        response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");          
        return;                             
    } else {            
        session.setAttribute("userLoggedIn", "false");              
        session.invalidate();
    }    
%>                                                                                                 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <body>      
        <form name="loginForm" method="post">           
            <table>             
                <tr>            
                    <td><input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit" class=button/></td>
                </tr>       
            </table>                                                    
        </form>
    </body> 
<%
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();    
    response.sendRedirect("login_first.jsp");           
    return;
} 
%>
</html>
```

main.jsp

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%
try {   
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);    
    if (session != null && "true".equals(session.getAttribute("userLoggedIn"))
            && !"Logout".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("logout"))) {        
        // do work          
    } else {        
        if (session != null) {
            session.setAttribute("userLoggedIn", "false");              
        }
        response.sendRedirect("login_first.jsp");           
        return;
    }    
%>                                                                                                 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <body>      
        <form name="creditCardForm" target="formresponse" autocomplete="off" method="post">                 
            <table width="50%" border=0 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1>            
                <tr>                    
                    <td>            
                        <div align="right">                                                                                    
                            <input name="logout" type="submit" class=button value="Logout">                           
                        </div>                  
                    </td>
                </tr>               
            </table>                    
            <iframe name="formresponse" width="0" height="0" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
        </form>
    </body> 
<%
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    response.sendRedirect("login_first.jsp");   
    return;
} 
%>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you aware that scriptlets are outdated?

Comment: @adarshr yes, but I am trying one urgent requirement.

Comment: Sure. But you could've just called main.jsp in the form's action attribute. Why are you doing a send redirect to go there?

Comment: I have some other functions in same jsp. I cant touch action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that the `target="formresponse"` in main.jsp gives problem. So I have moved this logout to a separate form and added action.

Comment: If this is the right solution, please mark your answer for others' reference.

Comment: sure, but I can accept my own answer only after 2 days. 6 more hours to go.

Answer (score 0):

First off, both pages have 'session=false' set but you're trying to get/set attributes in Session. Are you sure it's working at all as intended?

Second, you can only call response.sendRedirect() before any data was sent back to the client (before buffer flushed). Are you sure it's happening in your case?

Comment: For first question: works as fine. For second question, I want to do logout. so no data need to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

Although scriptlets are outdated, I believe you should check against the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) on where your JSP files are located and if you need to use a leading `/` on your redirect URLs; e.g. `/first_login.jsp` instead of `first_login.jsp`.

Comment: But the same sendRedirect is working from first_login.jsp. From main.jsp to login_first.jsp is not working.

Comment: Then I suppose the answer from @maximdim is more probable.

Answer (score 0):

> But the same sendRedirect is working from first_login.jsp. From
>   main.jsp to login_first.jsp is not working.

One reason could be that your main.jsp is in some subfolder.